# How to date add if end date is 1 day prior to the next rows start date

Tags: sql, sql-server, datediff, dateadd

I'm trying to total the days of both rows only if the end date of the first row is the day prior to the start date of the next row. If the end date of the first row is not one day prior to the second rows start date then I would like to exclude both of those rows from the query. So with the example below I should come to a sum of 365. My live table has thousands of rows with different names and orderids and I need to perform this task while keeping the integrity of the orderID for each individual.

| name | orderID | Start date | end date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Joe Smith | 1 | 2020-01-01 | 2020-09-30 |
| Joe Smith | 2 | 2020-10-01 | 2020-12-30 |

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.  SSMS suggests SQL Server.  What if there are multiple rows with that match your condition?

Answer (score 0):

If you want groups of more than one row that meet your condition, then this is a type of gaps-and-islands problem.

What you want to do is assign an "island" number to the rows.  You can do so by peaking at the previous row to see if it meets your condition.  If it does not, then an island starts.  A cumulative sum of the island starts assigns an island number to the groups.

The rest is aggregation

```
select name, min(startdate), max(enddate),
       datediff(day, min(startdate), max(enddate)) as num_days
from (select t.*,
             sum(case when prev_end_date <> dateadd(day, -1, startdate) then 0 else 1 end) over 
                 (partition by name order by startdate) as island
      from (select t.*,
                   lag(end_date) over (partition by name order by start_date) as prev_end_date
            from t
           ) t
     ) t
group by name, island
having count(*) > 1;
```

Comment: This is a great starting point, and worked well when I ran from my server. Unfortunately the query is also adding dates together when it shouldn't be. For example Row 1 end date is not the day prior to the row 2 start date, but these two rows are being totaled together.

My apologies if I'm missing something. Your SQL skills are much greater than my own.

Comment: The Row 1 end date *is* the day prior to the row 2 start date.

Answer (score 0):

Based this on @Gordon-Linoff's answer and his clue about gaps and islands, but I was getting incorrect adding in my test data as mentioned in a comment as well. I used this post as well
https://bertwagner.com/posts/gaps-and-islands/

```
-- test data
DECLARE @t TABLE (name varchar(50), orderID int, StartDate DateTime, EndDate DateTime);

INSERT INTO @t
SELECT 'Joe Smith', 1, '2020-01-01', '2020-09-30' UNION
SELECT 'Joe Smith', 2, '2020-10-01', '2020-12-30' UNION
SELECT 'Joe Smith', 3, '2021-01-01', '2021-09-30' UNION
SELECT 'Joe Smith', 4, '2021-10-01', '2021-12-31' UNION
SELECT 'Joe Smith', 5, '2022-01-01', '2022-09-30' UNION
SELECT 'Jane Doe', 6, '2020-01-01', '2020-09-30' UNION
SELECT 'Jane Doe',  7, '2020-11-01', '2020-12-30';

-- caculate the difference add 1 because EndDate is inclusive (ends on the start of next day)
SELECT t.*, d.IslandStartDate, d.IslandEndDate, DATEDIFF(DAY, IslandStartDate, IslandEndDate) + 1 AS Days FROM (
-- return the minimum and maximum start and end dates 
SELECT
    name, 
    MIN(StartDate) AS IslandStartDate,
    MAX(EndDate) AS IslandEndDate
FROM (
    SELECT
        *,
        -- indicates when a new island begins by looking if the current row's StartDate occurs after the previous row's EndDate
        CASE WHEN Groups.PreviousEndDate >= DATEADD(DAY, -1, StartDate) THEN 0 ELSE 1 END AS IslandStartInd,
        -- indicates which island number the current row belongs to
        SUM(CASE WHEN Groups.PreviousEndDate >= DATEADD(DAY, -1, StartDate) THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) OVER (PARTITION BY name ORDER BY Groups.RN) AS IslandId
    FROM
    (
        -- create a row number column based on the sequence of start and end dates, as well as bring the previous row's EndDate to the current row
        SELECT
            name,
            orderID,
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY name ORDER BY StartDate,EndDate) AS RN,
            StartDate,
            EndDate,
            LAG(EndDate,1) OVER (PARTITION BY name ORDER BY StartDate, EndDate) AS PreviousEndDate
        FROM
            @t
    ) Groups
) Islands
GROUP BY
    name, IslandId
) d
-- join to get the orderID back
INNER JOIN @t t ON d.name = t.name AND t.StartDate >= d.IslandStartDate AND t.EndDate <= d.IslandEndDate
ORDER BY IslandStartDate, name
```